# Combining Neo4J and MongoDB : Consistency

Tags: mongodb, transactions, neo4j, consistency

I am experimenting a lot these days, and one of the things I wanted to do is combine two popular NoSQL databases, namely Neo4j and MongoDB. Simply because I feel they complement eachother perfectly. The first class citizens in Neo4j, the relations, are imo exactly what's missing in MongoDB, whereas MongoDb allows me to not put large amounts of data in my node properties.

So I am trying to combine the two in a Java application, using the Neo4j Java REST binding, and the MongoDB Java driver. All my domain entities have a unique identifier which I store in both databases. The other data is stored in MongoDB and the relations between entities are stored in Neo4J. For instance, both databases contain a userid, MongoDB contains the profile information, and Neo4J contains friendship relations. With the custom data access layer I have written, this works exactly like I want it to. And it's fast.

BUT... When I want to create a user, I need to create both a node in Neo4j and a document in MongoDB. Not necessarily a problem, except that Neo4j is transactional and MongoDB is not. If both were transactional, I would just roll back both transactions when one of them fails. But since MongoDB isn't transactional, I cannot do this.

How do I ensure that whenever I create a user, either both a Node and Document are created, or none of both. I don't want to end up with a bunch of documents that have no matching node.

On top of that, not only do I want my combined database interaction to be ACID compliant, I also want it to be threadsafe. Both the GraphDatabaseService and the MongoClient / DB are provided from singletons.

I found something about creating "Transaction Documents" in MongoDB, but I realy don't like that approach. I would like something nice and clean like the neo4j beginTx, tx.success, tx.failure, tx.finish setup. Ideally, something I can implement in the same try/catch/finally block.

Should I perhaps make a switch to CouchDB, which does appear to be transactional?

**Edit :** After some more research, sparked by a comment, I came to realize that CouchDB is also not suitable for my specific needs. To clarify, the Neo4j part is set in stone. The Document Store database is not as long as it has a Java Library.

Comment: Where are you seeing transactions in CouchDb? Mongodb doesn't have transactions (by design). It seems like you want not only transactions, but possibly distributed transactions. You need to use a DB with transactions, or build a process that cleans up stale/disconnected data.

Comment: My bad. I was not well informed. I was reading a little about Couch DB but from the bits and pieces of information, I wrongfully deducted that they had ACID transactions. And yes, I am looking for distributed transactions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pieter-Jan,

if you are able to use Neo4j 2.0 you can implement a Schema-Index-Provider (which is really easy) that creates your documents transactionally in MongoDB.

As Neo4j makes its index providers transactional (since the beginning), we did that with Lucene and there is one for Redis too (needs to be updated). But it is much easier with Neo4j 2.0, if you want to you can check out my implementation for MapDB. (https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-mapdb-index)

Comment: Nice! Almost feel quilty for proposing another technology. ;-)

Comment: A-W-E-S-O-M-E! This is why I like Neo4j so much. When you can't find it in the documentation, there's always some clever dude that has a solution. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Ok, so I have been working on this, and I just want to check if I am going in the right direction with this. In stead of actually indexing a node, I just make sure that whenever a node is "indexed", what actually happens is that a document is created in the collection. I also enforced uniqueness so that you cannot have two documents for a single node. Now, to add information to those documents, I can just use a Mongo query to find the document and edit it, right?

Comment: @Pieter-Jan Have you found or written an Index Provider for MongoDB ?

Comment: I need to implement same kind of thing in my application . Do you share how you have done this ?

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm a huge fan of both technologies, I think a better option for you could be [OrientDB](http://www.orientdb.org/). It's a graph (as Neo4) and document (as MongoDB) database in one and supports ACID transactions. Sounds like a perfect match for your needs.

Comment: The Neo4j part is set in stone I'm afraid for various reasons, which include some beyond my "jurisdiction". But I also have some doubts about OrientDB. It seems like they try to be good at everything. And unfortunately, I am yet to find a product that tried that and succeeded. I might be wrong here, but somehow I doubt that OrientDB can provide a product that can compete with the top students in both the Graph DB class and the Document Store class. But off course that might just be me being cynical... And like you, I'm somewhat of a fan as well :D

Answer (score 0):

As posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465663/what-is-the-best-practice-to-combine-neo4j-and-mongodb?lq=1, you might have a look on Structr.

Its backend can be regarded as a Document database around Neo4j. It's fully transactional and open-source.